# Can not validate a cell in DataGridView

Tags: c#, validation, datagridview

I have been programming a winform application and in one form I have a dataGridView. A particular column is made of integers so the `DataTable` that is the source of the grid got defined as this

```
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  dt.Columns.Add("Partition", typeof(int));
  dt.Columns.Add("Number", typeof(int));
```

Anyway, later I try to validate this in order that the user does not introduce for example "dadada".

So I do

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{int result;
  if (!(int.TryParse(e.FormattedValue.ToString(), out result))) 
      {Trace.Writeline("error");
      return;
      }
}
```

`TryParse` is supposed to not throw an exception, and it handles it well until the last `}` when going out of the function it thows an exception.

I tried

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
        {

            int result=0;
            try
            {

                result = int.Parse(e.FormattedValue.ToString());
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("error");
                dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = 0;
                return;
            }
            if(result<0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("positives!");
                return;
            }

        }
```

And this time the catch catches the exception (of Parse) but then after that again another exception is produced while leaving the function.

I wonder what is wrong and how to validate the integer entrance of the grid

Comment: _"until the last { when going out of the function it thows an exception"_ You think that this exception is not relevant for your question or why you don't mention it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set [`Cancel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.canceleventargs.cancel?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_ComponentModel_CancelEventArgs_Cancel) to `true`:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = "";
    int result;

    // Don't try to validate the 'new row' until finished editing since there
    // is not any point in validating its initial value.
    if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].IsNewRow) { return; }
    if (!int.TryParse(e.FormattedValue.ToString(), out result))
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = "the value must be an integer";
    }
    else if(result < 0)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = "the value must be positive";
    }
}
```

MSDN [shows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvalidating?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) a good example.

Comment: Thank you! it seems to be working. The only thing is that the ErrorText remains even after I correct the input. I guess I have to erase the ErrorText when the validation goes well

Comment: @KansaiRobot: well, i'm doing that in the first line

Comment: Schemelter Oopps! I think I need a rest :| Thanks again